# Java: Why does the loop on a char 2D-array not include the last char?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, tic-tac-toe

I am new to Java and I am implementing a gameboard for the TicTacToe game. In order to clean the board after the game, I am trying to use a method, which with two nested loops will re-put the board exactly as at the beginning of the game. The problem is, that the last cells remain unchanged. This is my code:

```
public class CharLoopTest {
    static char[] [] board = {{'X','|','O','|','O'},
            {'_', '|', '_','|','O'},
            {'X','|','_','|','X'}};
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        clearBoard(board);
    }
    public static void clearBoard(char [] [] board) {
        for(int r = 0; r < board.length; r++){
            for(int c = 0; c < board.length; c++) {
                if(board[r][c] == 'X' || board[r][c] == 'O') {
                    board[r][c] ='_';
                }
                
            }    
        }
        printBoard(board);
    }
    public static void printBoard(char [] [] board) {   
        for(char [] row: board) {
            for(char column: row) { 
                System.out.print(column);   
            }
            System.out.println();   
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
_|_|O
_|_|O
_|_|X
```

I am struggling to figure out why the iterators do not reach the position [row][4] of the array length. I tried incrementing the index but so the int will iterate out of bounds. This is at the moment the only way it works:

```
public static void clearBoard(char [] [] board) {
        for(int r = 0; r < board.length; r++){
            for(int c = 0; c < board.length; c++) {
                if(board[r][c] == 'X' || board[r][c] == 'O') {
                     board[r][c] ='_';
                     board[0][4] = board[r][c]; //cleans last cells
                     board[1][4] = board[r][c];
                     board[2][4]= board[r][c]; 
                }
                
            }    
        }
        printBoard(board);
    }
```

Every hint would be really appreciated. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: `for(int c = 0; c < board.length; c++) {` The `board.length` is `3` but there are `5` columns in a row. You can use `for(int c = 0; c < board[r].length; c++) {`

Comment: Or even better, remove the `|` elements from the array. They are not part of the game data, just part of the display.

Comment: As a tip, do not include the `|` into your board. Your `char[][]` should be the representation of the board which is separate how it should be visualized. So adding the `|` is the task of the _"view model"_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you have a 3x5 grid. `board.length` then returns 3, and you are calling `board.length` even when you want to iterate over the contents of each array. If you change the condition in second for loop to  `c < board[r].length`, it will return the length of the r-th element, which is 5.